# how to do timer workflow

Tags: community, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

i want to activate timer workflow for the below scenario. i dont have much knowledge in salesforce. please help me with example or link.

Once a pet has received the maximum number of adoption requests or an adoption request for that pet has been open for more than 7 days, the assigned director must be notified to take action on the pet. The director can approve only a single adoption request for a pet. When selecting an adoption request, the director sets the status of the adoption request to ”Approved”.

Comment: You can user time trigger and create a email action for director. Email will fire after 7 days so you need to select created date + 7 days in time trigger.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245

Your question is also not that much clear, please add more detail of your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need implement an [Approval Processes](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=what_are_approvals.htm&language=en)
.If I read your request, which it needs to be a bit more clear, I can see that the **"director can approve a single adoption request for a pet"**. Based on that I think that an approval process will help you. 
You need to:

1. Find out the maximum number of **adoption requests**. Set this value to a field.
   Lest say the the field name is **"adoption requests"**, this will be in the API **adoption_requests__c**.
2. Now you need to come up with the maximum number for that field, lets say 10.
3. After this we have a indication for the **"maximum number of adoption requests".**
4. Now we need to deal with the **"open for more than 7 days"**. If you are tracking this on the **CreatedDate** field in SFDC you can just use this field in your Approval process logic.

Now, got to:

1. **Setup** (right to corner)
2. On the **"Quick Find/Search"** on you left top side type **"Approval Processes"**
3. On the drop down list select the Object you are using for this requests, the object that contains the information about the adoption requests.
4. Click on **"Create New Approval Process"**
5. Select **"Use Standard Setup Wizard"**
6. Give a name to the **"Process Name"** , hit tab
7. On the Specify **Entry Criteria** is where you set the logic to fire your approval.
8. You probably need to use a formula to trigger your approval. Something like:

   `IF(OR(CreatedDate==CreatedDate + 7)|| (adoption_requests__c ==10), true, false)`
   I haven't test the formula, it is more a indication on how you can start.
9. After you build your formula make sure to check your syntax and if is good to go click on next.
10. On that next page you can set the manager, I will suggest that you read the options on this page and how to configure this to your needs.
11. Set your **Record Editability Properties**.
12. Select the Template you want to use for your email alert. Click next
13. Now yo can set up the approval process view for those receiving those approvals. Take a look to that page and set your configuration. Click Next
14. Set up your **"Specify Initial Submitters"**. Click Save
15. After saving you can **"Create an Approval Step"**. Approval Process can hold different steps, so you need to think the logic you intend to use.
16. Go through all those steps and set it up as you may need. Is good to have an approval process document a side to have clear information on how to do it.
17. On of the most important steps on this configuration is the page: **"What Would You Like To Do Now?"** . In that page select the **"Email Alert"** option.
18. You need to set up all configurations for the **"New Email Alert"** page.

That will be more or less the process. Try things around and test them until you get what you want.

TIP: Do not forget to click on "Activate" after all is done. You can do that by going to the initial Approval Process for you object.

I hope this helps.